# Positive, Negative or Zero work done?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, work

In my physics course a practice question asks:

- Is there any work done in the following scenario: *A baby is carried across the room in his mother's arms.*

The answer according to the course is:[image]

I believe this is wrong and there is work done by the mother. Am I right? If you could explain your answer it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is often a point of confusion for people new to the concept of *work* in the physical sense. If we strictly look at the motion of the baby, carrying it is equivalent to placing it in a stroller and pushing it across the room. You can see that the stroller is not doing any work to keep the baby at the vertical position it is in. Assuming the stroller wheels to have no friction, there is also no work required to keep it moving across the room. The only point requiring energy input is accelerating and decelerating the stroller, and these amounts cancel exactly (one positive, one negative) if there is no friction, so no total work is done.

However, this is in contrast to our everyday experience, where just walking from A to B (without elevation change) requires us to exert some energy, even if no work in the physical sense is done to our body. This is due to the fact that there are lots of losses (chemical, friction, etc.) within our body and between out body and the environment. In this sense, you are right that the mother is exerting some energy to move about, but she is not performing work in the sense we usually mean in physics.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of work made by a force is $$W=\int\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r},$$ where $\vec{F}$ is the force and $d\vec{r}$ a differential displacement.

In your case, the force to hold the baby is "upwards in the vertical" (opposing to gravity), and the displacement is "horizontal", i.e. parallel to the floor, so the dot product between the force and the displacement is $0$.